# How would I add to an integer based on characters in a string?

Tags: c#

Basically, I'm creating a game and I have gotten to the stage where I need to add a score to an integer.

Lets say that the integer is called `totalScore`.

I currently have a string named spacedLetters which contains 7 letters randomly picked from a 26 letter array (the alphabet). I have created a simple:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter A Word:");
userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

Section that allows the user to input a word. All I want to do is to check through this string that they input (`userInput`) and add a value to `totalScore` based on what letters are in the word they inputted.

This should work a bit like scrabble as if they input `room`, it would value the `r`, then the `o`, then the other `o`, then the `m` and add a value that is assigned to these letters to the total score. I understand that I will need a reference table as well but I simply don't know how to do this.

TL;DR, I need a reference table for letters in the alphabet to correspond to a certain number (Like scrabble) and I need some code that checks through each letter in the users input and adds a value to a number based on if their word contains that letter. It also needs to account for duplicate letters, such as in the word room.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I ended up using the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (userInput.Contains(valueOf1[i]))
            {
                length1 = length1 + 1;
                totalScore = totalScore + 1;
            }
        }
```

People provided solutions but they were not what I was looking for, especially concerning my code, therefore no answer chosen.

Comment: So, a `Dictionary<char, int>`, against which you check the string's character array? What have you tried?

Comment: People aren't going to write the code for you, but it should be fairly simple. A [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) (as @CodeCaster suggested) and then just loop through the characters in your `userInput` (a simple `for` loop) and look up each letter in the dictionary, get the value and add it to `totalScore`. Give it a try and come back if you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You mention you know you need a reference table. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (userInput.Contains(valueOf1[i]))
            {
                length1 = length1 + 1;
                totalScore = totalScore + 1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following skeleton of an algorithm should do the trick (sorry for posting F# code, I tend to think faster in it than in C#; translating it should be quite straightforward, though):

```
let createRandomScores (n : int) =
    let r = System.Random ()
    let rec loop acc score =
        if score > n then dict acc else
            let x = char (r.Next (97, 123)), score
            loop (x :: acc) (score + 1)
    loop [] 1

let scoreDict = createRandomScores 6

let scoreWord (word : string) =
    let matchChar c =
        match scoreDict.TryGetValue c with
        | true, s -> s | _ -> 0
    word |> Seq.map matchChar
         |> Seq.sum

let addWordToScore score word =
    score + scoreWord word
```

**EDIT:** This might look as follows in C#:

```
static Dictionary<char, int> CreateRandomScores(int n)
{
    var r = new Random();
    var scores = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    for (var score = 1; score <= n; score++)
        scores[(char)r.Next(97, 123)] = score;
    return scores;
}

Dictionary<char, int> ScoreDict = CreateRandomScores(6);

static int ScoreWord(string word)
{
    var wordScore = 0;
    foreach (var c in word)
        if (ScoreDict.TryGetValue(c, out s))
            wordScore += s;
    return wordScore;
}

static int AddWordToScore(int score, string word)
{
    return score + ScoreWord(word);
}
```